# Facebook login for Android app : best practices

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication

What are the best practices  to implement a Facebook login in an Android app that already has an email password login activity as its main activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a official guide from Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers

it is a general guide for existing Logins in combination with social login.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide login using Facebook,Google,Twitter and more and keep all the accounts in synced. using [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/). So i would recommend checking it out